# Cordova error running on android emulator: "android: Command failed with exit code 2"

Tags: android, cordova

I'm trying to run my cordova project in an android emulator:

```
cordova emulate android
```

The build is successful but the emulator is not starting and I get an error:

```
Error: android: Command failed with exit code 2
```

I get the same thing when running `cordova requirements`:

```
Requirements check results for android:
Java JDK: installed 1.8.0
Android SDK: installed true
Android target: not installed
android: Command failed with exit code 2
Gradle: installed /opt/android-studio/gradle/gradle-3.2/bin/gradle
Error: Some of requirements check failed
```

I've upgraded Android SDK Tools to 26.0.1 and `android` command doesn't work for me anymore. So I installed `cordova-android@6.2.1` as the [release page](https://cordova.apache.org/announcements/2017/04/05/android-release.html) says and use it in my project:

```
$ cordova platform ls
Installed platforms:
  android 6.2.1
Available platforms:
  amazon-fireos ~3.6.3 (deprecated)
  blackberry10 ~3.8.0
  browser ~4.1.0
  firefoxos ~3.6.3
  ubuntu ~4.3.4
  webos ~3.7.0
```

But the error still happens. Does anyone has any ideas why this happens?

Comment: Sometimes after upgrading, I've found that I have to remove the android platform and readd it

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I think that a new version of Android SDK is not compatible with cordova emulation, so I change this:

```
return superspawn.spawn('android', ['list', 'avds'])
```

to this:

```
return superspawn.spawn('android', ['list', 'avd'])
```

inside

```
platforms/android/cordova/lib/emulator.js
```

and your error was fixed. That happens 'cause the command "android list avds" was changed to "android list avd" inside a new SDK. Thanx to [Douglas Neves](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6691730/douglas-neves)

If after that you'll catch another error like this:

```
Failed to install ... Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_VERSION_DOWNGRADE]
```

You'll need to change this:

```
var command = 'adb -s ' + target + ' install -r "' + apk + '"';
```

to this:

```
var command = 'adb uninstall "' + pkgName + '"; adb -s ' + target + ' install -r "' + apk + '"';
```

in the same file. This code will uninstall app before install it, so version problem will be disappeared.

Comment: Thanks! That totally solved it! This looks like something they missed in cordova-android 6.2.1

Comment: Has this been submitted as bug report to cordova?

Answer (score 6):

you should update latest platform:

```
cordova platform remove android
cordova platform update android@latest
```

Comment: It worked for me, you just have to add the platform before updating it : `cordova platform add android`

Answer (score -1):

You should save the whole workspace for ionic in under C drive with folder.

Execution failed for task ':mergeDebugResources' error will be resolved.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't really understand what you mean. I don't use Ionic or Windows. And the error you've mentioned wasn't occurring for me. Plus this questions already has an answer which points out precisely what went wrong in my case