# Ionic Emulate Android Error - Exit Code 2

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2, ubuntu-16.04

I'm running into trouble trying to run

```
ionic emulate android
```

I get an error which says `Error: android: Command failed with exit code 2` . But, it does say `BUILD SUCCESSFUL`.

---

What I'm running

1. Ubuntu 16.04.2
2. Node 6.10.2
3. NPM 3.10.10
4. Ionic 2.2.3
5. Cordova 6.5.0
6. Android Studio 2.3.1

---

I have set up environment variables in my .bashrc:

```
export ANDROID_HOME=$HOME/Android/Sdk
export PATH=${PATH}:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
```

---

Here is the the bottom of the output for `ionic emulate android`

```
UP-TO-DATE
  
BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 1.206 secs

Built the following apk(s): /home/matts-pc/Desktop/turn-app/platforms/android/build/outputs/apk/android-debug.apk

ANDROID_HOME=/home/matts-pc/Android/Sdk

JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64

Error: android: Command failed with exit code 2`
enter code here
```

---

Here is the output when I run `cordova run --list`

```
Available android devices:
Available android virtual devices:
ERROR: Error: android: Command failed with exit code 2
An unexpected error has occured while running list-emulator-images with code 2: Error: /home/matts-pc/Desktop/turn-app/platforms/android/cordova/lib/list-emulator-images: Command failed with exit code 2
```

---

Let me know if you need anything else! Thank you

Comment: Same issue here...

Answer (score 4):

Got an answer from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43354800/cordova-error-running-on-android-emulator-android-command-failed-with-exit-co/43364253) !

Inside `platforms/android/cordova/lib/emulator.js`:

Change:

`return superspawn.spawn('android', ['list', 'avds'])`

To:

`return superspawn.spawn('android', ['list', 'avd'])`

Change:

`var command = 'adb -s ' + target + ' install -r "' + apk + '"';`

To:

```
var command = 'adb uninstall "' + pkgName + '"; adb -s ' + target + ' install -r "' + apk + '"';
```

All credit to the original poster